# (verification) Left Distributive Property of Summation of Ordinals

Tags: proof-verification, ordinals

**claim**

$\forall \alpha, \beta, \gamma$ which are ordinals, 
$\alpha(\beta + \gamma) = \alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma$

**proof**

Let $\alpha = ord(X)$ $\beta = ord(Y)$ $\gamma = ord(Z)$ $\forall X,Y,Z$ which are finite-ordered set or $\Bbb N$.

$\alpha(\beta + \gamma) = ord(X \times(Y\cup Z))$ and

$ord(X \times(Y\cup Z)) = ord((X\times Y)\cup(Y\times Z))$ since

$X \times(Y\cup Z) = (X\times Y)\cup(Y\times Z)$.

Then $ord((X\times Y)\cup(Y\times Z))= ord(X\times Y) +ord(Y\times Z)$ since

$ord(A\cup B) = ord(A) + ord(B) \;\forall A,B$ which are finite well ordered set

Now, $ord(X\times Y) +ord(Y\times Z) = \alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma\;$  since

$ord(A\times B) = ord(A)ord(B) \;\forall A,B$ which are finite well ordered set.

Thus, $\alpha(\beta + \gamma) = \alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma$.

Comment: That would be left *distributivity*, not commutativity.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez edited. Is this proof well-dealing with the case of set $\Bbb N$ too?

Comment: It would be better to allow $X,Y,Z$ to be wosets in general, since when requiring then to be countable we can't contine for uncountable $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$

Comment: Also is $(X\times Y)\cup(Y\times Z)$ a typo of $(X\times Y)\cup(X\times Z)$?